# DownloadManager getFilesDir()

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I need to download the file to the internal memory of the device. I do it this way:

```
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getContext(),getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), name);
```

The file loads successfully. I need to check the presence of this file so I do not have to download it again:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), name);
if (!file.exists()) {
   ...
}
```

The check does not work, the file always loads again.
I also try to get a file for MediaPlayer()

```
String path = "file://" + getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name;
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(path));
```

This also does not work...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you waiting until the download has completed?   You need to set up a BroadcastReceiver to signal to your code when it has finished downloading.

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for the download to finish.

Comment: you are saving the file to device internal memory but while trying to get the file you are searching in app's private memory. Which is different from download localtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you are saving the file to device internal memory but while trying to get the file you are searching in app's private memory. Which is different from download localtion**

**setDestinationInExternalPublicDir**

> DownloadManager.Request setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (String dirType, 
>                   String subPath)
>   Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the public external storage directory (as returned by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)).
>
> The downloaded file is not scanned by MediaScanner. But it can be made scannable by calling allowScanningByMediaScanner().

**getFilesDir**

File getFilesDir ()

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.
>
> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.
>
> No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or write files under the returned path.

Comment: So how can I check if a file exists?